# Filtering out useless data from Python Api

Tags: python, api

I have written a bot that should print out the current price of a cryptocurrency, and I used coinmarketcaps api for this. However, if I print it out it's giving me all of the other useless data such as volume, supply etc. that I don't need.

```
from coinmarketcap import Market

coinmarketcap = Market()
print(coinmarketcap.ticker('Bitcoin', convert='USD'))
```

Please guide me. What is causing this problem?

Edit: This is the output I'm getting

```
[{'id': 'bitcoin', 'name': 'Bitcoin', 'symbol': 'BTC', 'rank': '1', 'price_usd': '2771.66', 'price_btc': '1.0', '24h_volume_usd': '1116730000.0', 'market_cap_usd': '45660983723.0', 'available_supply': '16474237.0', 'total_supply': '16474237.0', 'percent_change_1h': '-0.11', 'percent_change_24h': '7.18', 'percent_change_7d': '1.41', 'last_updated': '1501238672'}]
```

Comment: so what you need?

Answer (score 1):

You should print out the value you need from the object (in your case it is `price`), not the object itself, something like this:

```
from coinmarketcap import Market

coinmarketcap = Market()
price = coinmarketcap.ticker('BTC', convert='USD')

for item in price:
    print(item['price_usd'])
```

Comment: You beat me to it! was about to correct you on the list thing.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed the list after the question was edited with output :)